# Errors when import numpy package

Tags: python, numpy

I installed **numpy package** in python 3.6 successfully, but when i tried to import numpy i got errors. Please see attached image: [Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYYQP.jpg)

What i should do?
I have windows 10 (64 bit).

Comment: did u upgrade python ?

Comment: No. But i deleted Python 2.6 before two days. I had two version in my computer.  Now i have only one 3.6. This error happened in other computer too where i installed only one version of Python 3.6. The same that in two computers Windows 10.

Comment: Try updating python. The latest version is 3.6.2, while screenshot shows 3.6.0

Comment: delete python 3.6 and install both numpy and python again

Comment: Okay. I will try. Can you please explain me how can i should do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using python 3.6 (according to your screenshot), [this comment on the official numpy release](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases) should be relevant for you (as this is exactly the version your `pip install numpy` is grabbing), although that's not something i have much experience with, as i'm using [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) (recommended!) only.

> Note that the Python 3.6
>   wheels available from PIP are built against 3.6.1, hence will not work when
>   used with 3.6.0 due to Python bug 29943_. NumPy 1.13.2 will be released shortly
>   after Python 3.6.2 is out to fix that problem. **If you are using 3.6.0 the
>   workaround is to upgrade to 3.6.1 or use an earlier Python version**.

(bold annotations from me)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your numpy version to **1.12** , newer versions tend to be corrupted on Win10, check [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1508) out for more info, OR try upgrading your python version.

Comment: You're welcome, just be sure to select the correct answer as this, apparently, is an often occurring bug.

Comment: That link has nothing to do with OPs question as he does not use anaconda!